# How to test a file is readable as root?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions, root

I wrote a shell script that reads files in `/proc` and `/sys` (for example).
The script uses `if [ -r "$1" ]; then` to test if a file is readable before trying to read it.

Unfortunately it seems that `test -r` is succeeding, even if the file has no read permission (e.g. "`--w-------`"), but still an actual read (e.g. `file - <"$1"`) fails with "*Permission denied*".

(My guess is that `test` assumes `root` can read every file)

An example for such a file would be `/sys/devices/virtual/net/br0/bridge/flush` in Linux.

How can I test the "readable" property properly (and efficiently) in a shell script?

### More Details

```text
# ll -d /sys/devices/virtual/net/br0/bridge /sys/devices/virtual/net/br0/bridge/flush
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Mar  1 01:37 /sys/devices/virtual/net/br0/bridge
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Mar  1 07:58 /sys/devices/virtual/net/br0/bridge/flush
```

Comment: `stat -c '%A' file`? But you know that the root user is not impacted by file permissions as regular users are, do you? And also that some _files_ in `/proc` or `/sys` are not real files?

Comment: How do you define a "real file"? Also note that I use `file - <"$1"`, and not `file "$1"`. You should also elaborate how to extract actual read permissions from the string shown. Well, for `/sys` and `proc` there won't be ACLs soon, but for other files there could be.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about who can read the file (i.e. where the 'r' exists in permission bits), then you could use something like this:

```
if [[ `ls -l "$1" | cut -d " " -f1` =~ "r" ]]; then echo "Readable"; else echo "Unreadable"; fi
```

Otherwise, if you want to test a specific read bit (e.g. owner), then you could use something like this:

```
P=`ls -l "$1" | cut -d " " -f1`
if [[ "${P:1:1}" == 'r' ]]; then echo "Readable"; else echo "Unreadable"; fi
```

**Alternatively**, you could test the file readability as the user willing to run the command `file - <"$1"` as follows:

```
sudo -i -u someuser bash << EOF
if [ -r "$1" ]; then echo "Readable"; else echo "Unreadable"; fi
EOF
if [ -r "$1" ]; then echo "Readable"; else echo "Unreadable"; fi
```

Run the previous command as "root" and notice the output.

**P.S.** If you need to run the commands inside the script as some user, Why do you run the script as "root"?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: The script runs a `root` as most entries in `/sys` cannot be read otherwise.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano That is interesting. However, It is very unlikely to encounter a file with new-line in its name, specially under /proc or /sys directories.

Comment: @O.Salah my point is why parsing `ls` when there are better alternatives even if you may know there are presumably no special cases

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Just for the sake of simplicity. Specially, when you know for a fact that it would work well.

Answer (score 0):

To read the "r" bit of the user part of the permission bits ("`u+r`"), this command could be used, assuming it's a bit more efficient than https://stackoverflow.com/a/71460604/6607497 (using GNU sed 4.4):

```sh
stat -c %A "$1" | sed -n -e '/^.r/q0;q1'; echo $?
```

The command will exit with success (0) for permissions "`u+r`", with failure (1) otherwise.

However the file could be readable even when "`u+r`" is not true.
For example a normal directory without any read permissions *can be read* by `root`.

For files only, this is probably most efficient and correct for files) in `bash`:

```bash
{ local dummy=$(< "$1"); } 2> /dev/null
echo $?
```

The command will exit with success (0) when "$1" was readable, with failure (1) otherwise.
However for directories it will always exit with failure (1).

Answer (score 0):

Checking permissions using `stat --format %a` you could wrap the result into some modern shell code like this:

```bash
echo $(( $(printf '%o\n' $(( 0$(stat --format %a /etc/shadow) & 0444 ))) != 0 ))
```

That would output `1` is any of the read bits (`0444`) is set.
Of course the `printf %o` is not needed; it's just when you want to debug the result.

So:

```bash
# check whether file ($1) has any of the numeric permission bits ($2) set
check_perm_any_of()
{
    (( $((0$(stat --format %a "$1") & "$2")) != 0 ))
}
check_perm_any_of /etc/passwd 0444 && echo 1
check_perm_any_of /etc/passwd 0022 && echo 2
check_perm_any_of /etc/shadow 0004 && echo 3
check_perm_any_of /etc/shadow 0002 && echo 4
check_perm_any_of /etc/shadow 0200 && echo 5
```

will output:

```text
1
5
```